# VBA - error handing for non-existent web resource (Yahoo finance)

Tags: vba, excel

My macro generates yahoo ticker download URL's for specific companies. I generate 3 URL's per ticker, each having a different date segment for the data download.

The problem that I have, is that data does not exist for some of the dates, hence an error is returned from Yahoo which causes my Macro to crash.

I've attempted the following with a GOTO label:-

```
On Error GoTo error_handler
Workbooks.Open Filename:=("http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=FAN.L&a=2&b=04&c=2014&d=2&e=21&f=2014&g=d&ignore=.csv")
```

however this does not work, it does not GOTO the label.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please  give more context. Preferably give a [mcve]. Otherwise it is hard for others to do more than guess at what the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example of error handling. Replace your code with the `Debug.print 5/0` and it should work.

```
Public Sub ErrorHandlingExample()

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandlingExample_Error

    Debug.Print 5 / 0

    On Error GoTo 0
    Debug.Print "No error"

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandlingExample_Error:

    Debug.Print "Error was found - " & Err.Description

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
On Error Resume Next
Workbooks.Open Filename:=("http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=FAN.L&a=2&b=04&c=2014&d=2&e=21&f=2014&g=d&ignore=.csv")
On Error GoTo error_handler
```

The On Error Resume Next will allow it to the skip ahead.

Comment: If the *goal* is to catch the error a line might raise then it makes no sense to put an `On Error Resume Next` before the line, unless you immediately check `Err.Number` and act accordingly, something your code snippet fails to do.

Comment: There is no need to manage the error when you need it just to continue. The goal here was to prevent the program from stopping when the webpage was blank and allow it to move on to the next date. He could add an if err.number <> "" to note that that day was blank.

Comment: But OP *doesn't* want it to just continue. They have error-handling code for this line and were wondering why that error handling code seems to not be running despite an error being triggered. Your answer doesn't seem to address the question. Nobodies answer can really address the question since they haven't given enough information to go on. There is no reason to answer such a poor question.

Comment: He may not know he wants to just continue but that is what he needs to do.

Comment: Who knows? The fact that you have to guess about what they might know and what they might want underscores the fact that the question has very low quality. It is about as far from being a [mcve] as possible.

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable comments, I can only apologise for the low quality question, I appreciate it is fairly abstract but between all your replies I'm sure I will be able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Download the file with seperate error handling and then if-check

```
    If Dir(MyFileName) <> "" Then 
        Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\123.xls"             
    Else 
        MsgBox "Spreadsheet could not be found in C:\", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "File not found" 
    End If
```